# Appending text to each column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, concatenate

I have a Google Sheets that has about 200 columns. Each one is a name, and to each one, I want to append `-banner.jpg`. For example:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

will all be updated to:

```
abcde-banner.jpg
fghij-banner.jpg
klmno-banner.jpg
```

Is there a way to batch process this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

Find:  `(.+)`
Replace with: `$1-banner.jpg`
Search: `This sheet`
Search using regular expressions
Replace all.

Comment: Awesome. I just had to highlight/select the range I wanted. Cheers for that.

Comment: The latter - I only wanted a certain range and I had multiple columns. I didn't say that in the question because I thought I could figure that part out. Thanks again...I'm glad I know that works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "(.+)", "$1-banner.jpg"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A), A:A&"-banner.jpg", ))
```

[image: 0]